# how to send blob url to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, blob

I am using [Francium voice](https://github.com/subins2000/Francium-voice) recorder tool to record voice. When i click play button, below code is ran :

```
Fr.voice.export(function(url){
  jQuery("#audio").attr("src", url);
  jQuery("#audio")[0].play();
}, "URL");
restore();
```

on inspection i see audio element like below

```
<audio controls="" src="blob:https://example.com/33579f12-ee01-4dc2-9dda-82fb8d7d9307" id="audio"></audio>
```

Is there way to save this to a PHP server through `<form>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23511792/1372424

Comment: hey no i checked they are different , please can u help me with it , issue is that i want to click play button and after then save to server get disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt something like:

```
var file = $('#yourFileInput').get(0).files.item(0);
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'yourUploadURL.php', 
    data: file, 
    contentType: 'application/my-binary-type',
    processData: false 
});
```