# How do I set the value of a file input to a blob dynamically?

Tags: javascript, blob

This is my code...

What I want to do:

1. Record the audio of the user save it as a blob
2. Make the recorded audio equal to the value of the file input tag...

What I have achieved:

1. Recording and converting to blob is done

How do I make the value of the input file tag equal to the blob?

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' });
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
    // document.querySelector('#id_audio').value = 'How to do this?';
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: I understand the security reasons... but in this case I am not taking any files from user's system, I want to make the value of the input equal to a blob which is an audio file recorded in the browser itself...

Comment: Alright check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511792/attach-a-blob-to-an-input-of-type-file-in-a-form/66466855#66466855

Comment: Thanks a ton... You helped me a lot. I was struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: You're welcome :D