# Using Javascript to send file to file input value?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

Here is where I have established the .mp3 file as a file

```
const file = new File(buffer, 'audio.mp3', {
  type: blob.type,
  lastModified: Date.now()
});
```

How would I go about using the (const file variable) to pass it thru a form?

Comment: What in the world do you mean by pass a variable through a form? If you want to add it to a form's file input, use `document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files.push(file);`

Comment: The const file is an object file, but the form wont accept it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466855/19068) on the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to send it to a php page, thats not possible you wanna set a javascript object in a php $_POST or $_GET variable, thats not possible!

You could send it via ajax-call to your .php